# Regular expression for counting decimals

Tags: regex

I need to validate a Textbox input which accepts decimal values. I require to count the number of digits entered after dot in the decimal number and restrict if the precision is more than 5.

Ex
Valid values 
1.2
15.256
25.25486

Invalid
455.256485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\d*(?:\.\d{1,5})?$
```

This should validate decimals with `5` after `.`.

```
^\d*(?:\.\d{1,5})$
```

Use this if it is striclty for decimals and not integers.

Comment: It's not strictly decimals, but in the first one ie "^\d+(?:\.\d{1,5})?$" if I give just '.26' its validating as invalid. Can you please help me with the modified expression.